# 3.5mm audio sound quality in ubuntu

Tags: sound, alsa, speakers, ubuntu-drivers

Static sound can be heard in headphones on ubuntu. It is not an issue of headphones as this issue does not exists in windows.

Comment: Maybe the same fix can be applied, maybe not. Some really depend on proprietary software/drivers/codecs that aren't available except for the factory default OS.

Comment: That did work in every combination of options selected in the dropdown boxes in alsa tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be resolved using **alsamixer**.
In Terminal write

```
    > alsamixer
```

Adjust Headphone Mic boost to 10db
Hope this will resolve this issue